# Package a Cordova app in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

How can I set the configurations of the picture below? I'm using Visual studio cordova template.

Example, how can I set the Minimum SDK Version? Do I just write 2.3?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you noticed this [Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/#get_started_articles) documentation site.

Also visit https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/win8/

According to your question:

> how can I set the Minimum SDK Version? Do I just write 2.3?

I think version number like 2.3 is enough. VS 2015 should recognize it

Comment: so it might be an API Version like instead of 2.3 use 9